# TypeError: get() Missing 1 requerid positinional argument:"self"

Tags: python

Como puedo hacer que este programa ***CRUD*** pueda reconocer una matricula, yo en mi caso trato de agarrar desde `getMatricula()` para obtener el valor y tratarlo de buscar en el array de `aAlumno[Estudiante.getmatricula()]` y así con este encontrar la matricula de algún alumno, obviamente el usuario debe de ingresar la matricula del alumno para poder encontrarlo. Para que puedan ver mejor, les muestro la clase del alumno:

```
class Estudiante:
    matricula = 1000
    def __init__(self, nombre, calificacion):
        Estudiante.matricula += 10
        self.setName(nombre)
        self.setQualifi(calificacion)
        self.__matricula = Estudiante.matricula

    def getMatricula(self):
        return self.__matricula

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def getQualifi(self):
        return self.__qualifi

    def setName(self, nombre):
        self.__name = nombre

    def setQualifi(self, calificacion):
        self.__qualifi = calificacion

    def __str__(self):
        return "El alumno " + self.getName() + " con la matricula " + str(self.getMatricula()) + " tiene una calificacion de " + str(self.getQualifi())
```

Y aquí el programa es donde se ejecuta:

```
from Estudiante import Estudiante
def Buscar(aAlumno):
    indice = -1
    busMatricula = int(input("Ingrese la matricula del alumno que busca: "))
    matricula = aAlumno[Estudiante.getMatricula()]
    for i in range(len(aAlumno)):
        if matricula[i] == busMatricula:
            indice = i
            print(i)
    return indice
aAlumno = []
opcion = 1
while opcion != 0:
    print("\n------------------------\n\tMenu\n------------------------\n[1] Agregar alumno\n[2] Modificar alumno\n[3] Eliminar alumno\n[4] Mostrar lista de alumnos\n[5]Buscar\n[0] Salir")
    opcion = int(input("Ingrese la opcion de deseada: "))
    elif opcion == 5:
        aAlumno = Buscar(aAlumno)
```

En el programa me sale el `TypeError:getMatricula() Missing 1 requerid positional argument: "self"` en la parte del `Buscar()`; El código es mas grande pero lo demás creo que esta bien, bueno, en si necesito el `def Buscar()` para poder terminar lo demás. Espero y puedan ayudarme :).

Comment: Intente una respuesta, pero hay tantos errores conceptuales y de lógica en la función `Buscar` que daría para un tratado.

Answer (score 0):

yo diría que el problema está en que no has creado una instancia de Estudiante, y llamas al método getMatricula como si fuera un método estático.

Si el parámetro aAlumno que recibe la función Buscar es una instancia de la clase Estudiante, deberías cambiar lo siguiente:

```
matricula = aAlumno.getMatricula()
```

Answer (score 0):

El código `Estudiante.py` está bien, pero el tratamiento de los alumnos está mal.

Si tienes un conjunto de alumnos, debes guardarlo en alguna estructura. Dado que los alumnos se identifican por su matrícula, la solución obvia es usar un diccionario indexado por matricula.

Voy a crear dos estudiantes, que tendrán su matricula asignada automáticamente:

```
est1 = Estudiante("juan", 50)
est2 = Estudiante("jorge", 60)
```

luego los pongo en un diccionario que contiene todos los alumnos:

```
alumnos = {
    est1.getMatricula(): est1,
    est2.getMatricula(): est2
}
```

Aqui lo imprimo:

```
for k, v in alumnos.items():
    print(k, v)
```

y acá proceso las consultas del usuario:

```
llave = int(input("Matricula a buscar: "))
if llave in alumnos:
    print(f"Maricula {llave} corresponde a {alumnos[llave]}")
else:
    print("matricula inexistente")
```

produce:

```
1010 El alumno juan con la matricula 1010 tiene una calificacion de 50
1020 El alumno jorge con la matricula 1020 tiene una calificacion de 60
Matricula a buscar: 1010
Maricula 1010 corresponde a El alumno juan con la matricula 1010 tiene una calificacion de 50

Process finished with exit code 0
```